# Stub layouts for Android Tests Not Found

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-layout

I'm trying to test a custom view using the Android testing framework. I copied the `LinearLayoutTest` [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/android-4.4.2_r2/tests/tests/widget/src/android/widget/cts/LinearLayoutTest.java) from Android CTS source as an example. This uses a `LinearLayoutStubActivity` which just inflates a layout.

I have a few issues:

- When I create the `linearlayout_layout.xml` file in my `androidTest/res/layout` folder, Android Studio can't even find the `xmlns:android` URI. Not a big issue but indicates that something is not right. AS shows the appropriate highlighting for folders so I know AS is considering these as source folders.
- The `LinearLayoutStubActivity` one sets content view to `R.layout.linearlayout_layout` but linearlayout_layout can't be found.
- Obviously the same is true of any reference to resources within the actual test code.

Running the tests from command line gradle fails with the expected `cannot find symbol` errors.

There are a few questions related to testing custom views on SO and the appropriate way does seem to be inflating it within an Activity context but it seems like this is impossible without writing a separate app that just does the testing. I believe that is how the testing in the Android source would work too. One app just has dummy layouts and another does the actual testing. Is that the only way to do something like this ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding an import statement in the LinearLayoutStubActivity that references the androidTest res folder? It would be in the form of

```
import com.packagename.test.R;
```

instead of the normal import statement of

```
import com.packagename.R;
```